# Focus UITextfield in Custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I have 2 `UITextfield` in custom cell. And now I want to set focus on this first text field when push from other view.

[image]

Here is my code for in `cellForRowAt` delegate but this doesn't work:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InputUserInfoForm") as! InputUserInfoForm
        userCell.selectionStyle = .none

        userCell.fistnameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
        userCell.lastnameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no

        // Firstname textfield
        userCell.fistnameTextField.tag = RegisterForm.Firstname.rawValue
        userCell.firstnameLabel.text = "FirstnameTitle".localized()
        userCell.firstnameLabel.becomeFirstResponder()

        // Lastname textfield
        userCell.lastnameTextField.tag = RegisterForm.Lastname.rawValue
        userCell.lastnameLabel.text = "LastnameTitle".localized()

        return userCell
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting this code in `cellForRowAt`? It seems better suited for `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, you have multiple cells, and all of them are instructed to `becomeFirstResponder` every time they're drawn.

If you want to set focus only on the first cell when the table is displayed, and only then, you can tag that `UITextField` when `indexPath.row == 0` and in `viewDidAppear` you simple get that field with the tag and set the `becomeFirstResponder`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InputUserInfoForm") as! InputUserInfoForm
    userCell.selectionStyle = .none

    userCell.fistnameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    userCell.lastnameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no

    // Firstname textfield
    userCell.fistnameTextField.tag = RegisterForm.Firstname.rawValue
    userCell.firstnameLabel.text = "FirstnameTitle".localized()
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        userCell.firstnameLabel.tag = 123
    }

    // Lastname textfield
    userCell.lastnameTextField.tag = RegisterForm.Lastname.rawValue
    userCell.lastnameLabel.text = "LastnameTitle".localized()

    return userCell
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.view.viewWithTag(123)
}
```

Comment: @ManhNguyen I see you're new on stackoverflow. If this answer solved your problem don't forget to mark it as accepted. Thanks.